# Nativescript image not updating

Tags: typescript, event-handling, nativescript

So I have an image 2 images in me resource files. I have one Image element in a list view. When the image is tapped it is supposed to update the image src property like this:

```
<Image id="imgFav" stretch="none" cssClass="icon-image" src="{{ favourite ? 'res://ic_add_to_fav_1' : 'res://ic_add_to_fav' }}"/>
```

It is actually updating in memory however the result is not reflected unless I scroll away from the list item and back to it.

I have a setter which looks like this:

```
set favourite(value: boolean) {
        if (this._favourite !== value && this._session.isBreak) {
            this._favourite = value;
            this.notify({ object: this, eventName: Observable.propertyChangeEvent, propertyName: "favourite", value: this._favourite });
        }
    }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: When you are using ObservableArray the ListView will be automatically updated when items are added or removed form the array. If you change the source of the image in the above given way, the ListView will not be auto refresh. One way to solve your problem is to use ListView `refresh`method, after you update the image source -http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_list_view_.listview.html#refresh .

Comment: I am not ever sure what I did wrong in this instance however I got it working when I re made it from scratch. I wish I knew exactly what was up in this case though.